# How do I enable 4 finger swipe on Synaptics touchpad 7.2 on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, gestures, synaptics-touchpad

I have driver version 16.3.1.2. It's not available in the control panel applet. I have tried the registry hack to change visibility but that did not work. How do I enable the 4 finger swipe?

Comment: Possibly related: [Three finger swipe to change between windows](http://superuser.com/questions/526210/three-finger-swipe-to-change-between-change-windows)

Comment: That is asking for a feature not supported by the driver. What I'm asking for (4 finger swipe) is in the driver, it's not showing up on my computer for some reason. For example, the tutorial video is on my computer and the codes are in the registry too, it's just not showing up in the control panel applet.

Comment: Have you tried to delete and reinstall the driver? Or tried to revert to an older version? Or even updated if a newer release is perhaps available?